# ¿Por qué en Colombia se dice "nos estamos viendo / leyendo / hablando" para decir "hasta pronto"?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos, saludos, colombia

Mis amigos colombianos con frecuencia cosas como:

> - Bueno, me voy. **Nos estamos viendo**.
>
> - Me tengo que ir. ¡**Nos estamos hablando**!

Yo lo entiendo como un "hasta luego", "seguimos en contacto" e incluso me parece muy parecido al usado en España "nos vemos".

Sin embargo, me parece una expresión la mar de peculiar, pues tomada literalmente invita a contestar "claro, estamos hablando ahora mismo" "por supuesto, estamos viéndonos porque estamos uno delante del otro".

Es por ello que me pregunto: ¿cómo surge esta expresión? ¿la entiendo bien? ¿se usa también en otros países?

Comment: Esto es lo que se conoce como *planes en el futuro.*   El plan es verse de nuevo, pero se acostumbra a usar la forma continua.  En inglés, lo usan para los *future arrangements*.  En Chile lo usamos a cada rato. ¿El origen? Ni idea.

Comment: 1) tu lectura es correcta 2) yo creo que es el resultado de *extender* el presente del *seguimos en contacto* (que implica un proceso que puede ser interrumpido, pero no termina aún) a contextos en los que pasa a ser menos aplicable. Mal que mal, el tiempo verbal (*estar* + vebo + *-ando*) se llama *presente continuo*, con lo que se agrega al presente (nos vemos ahora) una continuidad (nos seguiremos viendo o ya nos estábamos viendo).

Comment: Es comun en inglés http://www.examenglish.com/grammar/A2_present_continuous_for_future.htm

Comment: En Chile a veces se usa algo parecido para los compromisos. P.ej. -Mañana voy a hacer una parrillada. -_¡De allá somos!_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La expresión, que yo sepa también se usa en Ecuador. (Viví en Ecuador y soy Colombiano)

Literalmente es **Nos estamos hablando**. Quiere decir que incluso si no nos vemos, vamos a seguir hablando. Es decir nos estamos hablando todavía.

Yo diría que es el equivalente a

> Estamos en contacto o Seguimos en contacto

Exactamente como tu interpretación.

"Nos estamos hablando" por su forma es un gerundio, una forma continua, pero con una pequeña *nuance* del futuro próximo.

Pienso que en Colombia se dice **Nos estamos hablando** en vez de **Hasta pronto** porque hasta pronto implica que no nos hablaremos hasta vernos de nuevo. Puede que sea algo cultural, dado que en Colombia a la gente le gusta tener mucho contacto con los otros, sobre todo los amigos.

Comment: No acabo de entender lo de _Quiere decir que incluso si no nos vemos, vamos a seguir hablando_. ¿Se refiere a que estaremos en contacto, aunque sea virtual / epistolar / telefónico?

Comment: @fedorqui Sí exacto, a mi interpretación es que estaremos en contacto por otros medios. Que sea por amigos o virtualmente. Pienso que va de la mano con nuestro **Mándale saludes a X**

Comment: ¡Qué interesante! Siempre lo interpreté como una equivalencia exacta a nuestro "hasta pronto", que sí asume (o al menos yo lo hago) que nos veremos físicamente.